# why the php condition not work unless i echo the variable?

Tags: javascript, php

in the code below, if I echo the variable the condition will work if I don't echo the variable the condition will not work!

what is the error?

the code:

```
$msg=$_SESSION['$msg'];
echo $msg;
if($msg != null){ ?>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9"></script>
<script >
    swal.fire({
                icon: "success",
                title: "success",
                showConfirmButton: false,
                timer: 1300
        })
 </script>

<?php } ?>
```

edited code: even this does not work unless echo!

```
$msg="ss";
if(!empty($msg)){ ?>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9"></script>
<script >
    swal.fire({
                icon: "success",
                title: "success",
                showConfirmButton: false,
                timer: 1300
        })
 </script>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: `echo` nothing to do with condition.  there is also a `is_null()`

Comment: use  `if( !empty( $msg ) )`

Comment: the code works fine if echo exists if I remove echo the code will not work!

Comment: `echo` should not effect the condition. also is `$_SESSION['$msg']` correct? (may be its ['msg'] instead of `['$msg']`) ?

Comment: Are you sure about this line: `$msg=$_SESSION['$msg'];`? IMO it should probably be `$msg=$_SESSION['msg'];`

Comment: i dont have to echo the variable, but I have to echo anything to work the condition, I don't know why!

Comment: its not the session error! works fine to get the session variable! i edited the coed the same problem I have to echo, tack a look to the code please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few problems in the code:

1. Call `session_start();` before using $_SESSION.
2. `$_SESSION['$msg']` can be undefined and can trigger notice. You should check if the key exists with `isset($_SESSION['$msg'])`.
3. Session key `$msg` is a bit strange. You don't need the `$` for session keys.
4. If you want to check for not `null`, use strict comparison `!==`.

```
<?php 
session_start();
$msg = isset($_SESSION['$msg']) ? $_SESSION['$msg'] : null;
echo $msg;
if($msg !== null){ ?>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9"></script>
<script >
    swal.fire({
                icon: "success",
                title: "success",
                showConfirmButton: false,
                timer: 1300
        })
 </script>

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Firstly, in line number 1 you should pull the session key, so if its a variable it should be 
$msg=$_SESSION[$msg]; 
else it should be the key name
$msg=$_SESSION['msg']; //msg can be replaced by your key name.

You can check directly whether the key exist or not and if it is empty as below: 
       if(isset($_SESSION['msg']) && $_SESSION['msg'] != ''){ ?>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9"></script>
        <script >
        swal.fire({
                    icon: "success",
                    title: "success",
                    showConfirmButton: false,
                    timer: 1300
            })
       </script>
    
       <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: @nico haase Added comments.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).